# mysql date comparison using BETWEEN in MySQL JSON data

Tags: mysql, json, date-range, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I'm struggling to compare dates which are stored in JSON data in MySQL.

The format of the JSON would be something like

`{"0": {"end_date": "2018/06/30", "start_date": "2018/06/01"},
"1": {"end_date": "2018/06/30", "start_date": "2018/06/01"}}`

So, now I need to write a MySQL query to fetch the row only if the date in the JSON is BETWEEN '2018/06/01' and '2018/06/05'.

Any alternate suggestions instead of storing in JSON also welcome.

Comment: mysql version ?

Comment: MySQL version ==> MySQL 5.7+

Comment: What do you mean with "JSON is BETWEEN"?  Since you have several dates in that JSON, do you mean that *all* four of them should be between the given dates, or only the `start_date`s should be or is just one match is enough (with either `start_date` or `end_date`)? It would be good if you could provide an example with several records (for different situations) and the expected outcomes for them.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use generated columns on start data and end date to make the SQL much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is a bit old but I had the same problem so I decided to post my solution, hope it can help someone.

For that, I use the `JSON_TABLE` function to generate a table where I can use the fields inside a `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT t.* FROM table t
    INNER JOIN JSON_TABLE(
        t.json_field,
        '$[*]'
        COLUMNS(
            `start_date` DATE PATH '$.start_date',
            `end_date` DATE PATH '$.end_date'
        )
    ) AS j
    ON <input_date> BETWEEN j.start_date AND j.end_date;
```

The only problem is that your JSON string has an object format and not an array, to make the code above work the string would be:

```json
[
  { "end_date": "2018-06-30", "start_date": "2018-06-01" },
  { "end_date": "2018-06-30", "start_date": "2018-06-01" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually store the start_date as DATE and the end_date as DATE. So you'd have two columns for the dates.

Then you could simply `SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE start_date >= 2018-06-01 AND end_date <= 2018-06-05`

Comment: He wrote: "Any alternate suggestions instead of storing in JSON also welcome." ... but OK, better downvote it ;)

Comment: @maio290 Thankx bt that cannot be achieved as I have multiple dates to be stored per row

Comment: Hm, my SQL is too limited to provide a solution for your problem, but you could use SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX, REPLACE and CAST to extract the values from the string, bring it into a SQL Date format, cast it into a DATE and then compare it with a static Date. However, I guess you have your reasons to store the data like that, but it's rather unintuitive. SQL isn't really made for evaluating JSON.